# PowerShell 2.0 Writing to a text file created from an array without prior knowledge of name

Tags: powershell, service, powershell-2.0, monitoring

I am writing a script that will take a text file with one service per line and check to see whether the service exists, and if it is running or not.  This text file will be different on different machines and can be a different number of lines.

I have the script read the file and create text files with the names of all the services that the text file is looking for.  After that I want it to check to see if the service exists, and if it exists to see if it is running.  If it exists and is running I don't want the script to do anything.  However, if the service exists, but is not running, I want it to increment a variable and send an email if appropriate.

The script is incrementing the variable when it runs correctly, but it is not reading from, nor writing to the dynamically generated text files.  Also, it stops after checking the first service and does not continue to iterate through all the services.  The emails are being sent just fine, but the variables are not incrementing so it is generating an email everytime.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This script has been modified to a more generic version that will not affect the code structure.

Example of the MonitoredServices.txt

W32Time

BITS

Then in the C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Monitored location the following text files would be created, both with a default value of zero as the only information in the file.  This is the value I am trying to get the script to read and write to:

W32Time.txt

BITS.txt

```
$Monitored = "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\MonitoredServices.txt"
$Services = (Get-Content $Monitored)
$toemail = (Get-Content -path "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Service_Monitor_To_Address.txt")
$fromemail = (Get-Content -path "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Service_Monitor_From_Address.txt")
$Computer_Name = hostname
$path = "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Monitored"
$time = Get-Date -format T

function Email-Alert {
Send-MailMessage -To $toemail -Subject "$line on $Computer_Name is not running" -Body "$line on $Computer_Name is not running as of $time" -SmtpServer "255.255.255.255" -From $fromemail -Priority High
}

ForEach ($line in $Services) {
    If (-not (Test-Path -path $path\$line.txt)){
        New-Item -Path $path\$line.txt -type file
        Set-Content $path\$line.txt "0"}}

ForEach ($line in $Services) {
    $file = "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Monitored\$line.txt"
    [int]$value = Get-Content $file
    Get-Service -displayname $line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If ($line.length -gt 0){ 
            If ($line.status -ne "Running"){
                If ($value -lt 4){
                    $value++
                    Set-Content $value $file
                    Email-Alert
                    Break}
                ElseIf ($value -lt 10){
                    If ($value %2 -ne 0){
                        $value++
                        Set-Content $value $file
                        Break}
                    Elseif ($value %2 -eq 0){
                        $value++
                        Set-Content $value $file
                        Email-Alert
                        Break}
            }}}}
```

The suggestion by TheMadTechnician has resolved the issue of the script not reading all of the services, however the file is still not incrementing or reading correctly.  Also if the service does not exist it is sending out an email as if the service is not running.  Here is the modified script.  Everything above the second ForEach code is unchanged.  The reason for the If and ElseIf within the switch command is that I want after the first set to only generate an email every other time and then every 5th time the service has failed.

```
ForEach ($line in $Services) {
$file = "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Monitored\$line.txt"
[int]$value = Get-Content $file
$CurrentService = Get-Service -displayname $line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     If ($CurrentService.status -ne "Running"){
         Switch ($value){
                {$_ -lt 4} {
                    $value++
                    Set-Content $value $file
                    Email-Alert
                    Continue}
                {$_ -lt 10} {
                    If ($_ %2 -ne 0){
                        $_++
                        Set-Content $_ $file
                        Continue}
                    Elseif ($_ %2 -eq 0){
                        $_++
                        Set-Content $_ $file
                        Email-Alert
                        Continue}}
                {$_ -gt 10} {
                    If ($_ %5 -ne 0){
                        $_++
                        Set-Content $_ $file
                        Continue}
                    Elseif ($_ %5 -eq 0){
                        $++
                        Set-Content $_ $file
                        Email-Alert
                        Continue}}}
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a few things of note here...

```
ForEach ($line in $Services) {
    $file = "C:\serverMonitor\Server_Monitor\Monitored\$line.txt"
    [int]$value = Get-Content $file
    Get-Service -displayname $line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If ($line.length -gt 0){ 
            If ($line.status -ne "Running"){
```

You're running a ForEach loop and using $Line as the current iteration. That's fine, but at any given time $Line = service name, just a string, so how exactly are you trying to evaluate anything against $line.status? I'll tell you now, $line.status will never = "Running" with the code you have shown.

On that note, Get-Service blah, blah, parameters, arguments. So you really wanted that to just echo to the screen? I think what you really wanted to happen was to have `$CurSrvc = Get-Service -displayname $line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and then in your If statement do `If($CurSrvc .status -ne "Running"){` and go from there.

Next, `Break`... just don't. Use Continue, that's what you want it to do, at least as far as PowerShell is concerned. Continue moves to the end of the current loop's scriptblock, so it will move on to the next record if there is one.

Lastly, your `If(){}ElseIf(){If(){}ElseIf(){}}` makes me cringe. This is where the Switch cmdlet comes in handy. Take a look at this:

```
Switch($value){
    {$_ -lt 4}               {$value++
                              Set-Content $value $file
                              Email-Alert
                              Continue}
    {$_ -lt 10 -and $_ -ne 0}{$value++
                              Set-Content $value $file
                              Continue}
    {$_ -lt 10 -and $_ -eq 0}{$value++
                              Set-Content $value $file
                              Email-Alert
                              Continue}
}
```

Or even better yet, since the If($value -lt 4) is going to move to the next record, that makes checking if it = 0 pointless, so really all you are doing is if $value -lt 4 do one thing, otherwise if $value -lt 10 do another. If it is over 10 I guess you just don't care. The only difference between being less than 4 and over 4 is if you send an email. Let's simplify things:

**Edit:**

```
If(($value -lt 4) -or ($value -ge 4 -and $value -lt 10 -and $value %2 -eq 0) -or ($value -ge 10 -and $value %5 -eq 0))  {Email-Alert}
$value++
Set-Content $value $file -force
```

Ok, skipping the switch now that I understand what you want. That will check if it is under 4, OR greater than or equal to 4, under 10, and an even number OR greater than or equal to 10, and a multiple of 5. If it is one of those three things it will generate an email. Then it iterates $value and outputs to the file.

Comment: I have applied these recommended changes and one issue has been resolved (It is now parsing all the entries), however the file is still not being incremented correctly, and it is also generating emails for services that don't exist.  I will update the question with the new code I have implemented.

Comment: See if my update doesn't work better for you. It checks if $value meets your conditions, and sends an email if it does. Then it iterates $value and updates the file for all of them.